# Is there an ATM at or near Vágar Airport?

Tags: atms, faroe-islands

When we arrive at Vágar Airport (FAE), will there be an ATM in the airport? (If not), what about the nearby town of Sørvágur?

Answer (score 3):

Two are shown at https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/consumers/get-support/locate-an-atm.html

A DuckDuckGo search for `ATM locator` shows many options.  Above is the second hit.  First hit was Visa and it said there were none in 600 kilometers of either of your locations.

You can also see them on Open Street Map, or if you want a list, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684689/open-street-maps-query-for-atm

Comment: The master card locator shows one at "OVARIEVEGUR 5, SØRVÁGUR, VÁGAR". The location on the map for this one is very likely wrong: on a steep mountain slope in the middle of nowhere. But address suggests it's located in the town I was looking for. It's not listed on the openstreetmap data, though, so either this is incomplete or the atm is a ghost.

Comment: OSM is crowd-sourced, like Wiki.  I've found lots of errors in it, and it tends to be empty where no one has gone to take notes.  OSM does show a bank in Sørvágur near the Sports Ground.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be an ATM at the airport, but I am actually not sure if there still is one in the new terminal :-) See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsKqPSE65RI

But there are ATMs both in Sørvágur and Miðvágur near the airport.

And if you are traveling to Tórshavn with bus, there is one at the busterminal.

See also: http://www.visitfaroeislands.com/plan-your-stay/before-you-arrive-in-the-faroe-islands/money/